# Why is there module search path instead of typing the directory name + typing the file name?

Tags: python, import, module-search-path

Is there an advantage? What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So that everyone doesn't need to have *exactly* the same file structure on their hard drive?  `import C:\Python\lib\module\` probably wouldn't work too well on my Mac...

Edit: Also, what the heck are you talking about with the working directory?  You can *certainly* use modules outside the working directory, as long as they're on the `PYTHONPATH`.